# React Native making calls after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

```js
const update=async()=>{
        
        setUpdatedUser({
          ...updatedUser,
          userType:user?.userType,
          hostStatus:(user?.userType=='host')?true:false,
          verificationStatus:false
        })
        await actors.userActor?.updateUserInfo(updatedUser).then(async(res)=>{
            console.log(res)
            alert('processing')
            alert(`Your profile is updated ${updatedUser?.firstName} !`)
            await actors.userActor?.getUserInfo().then((res)=>{
                dispatch(setUser(res[0]))
                console.log("response user",res[0])
                setEditProfile(false)
            })
        })
        console.log("request user",updatedUser)
    }
```

I am facing an issue with asynchronous handling of functions,  I am trying to execute my update function on a button click but it is not returning any response or error but when I am navigating to another screen I am getting my responses, it seems like update is executing when I am navigating to another screen. Why is it happening and how to solve this?
I am using redux toolkit for state management and I have verified my backend as well where I am making my calls

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the API request when navigating to another screen using AbortController

```
useEffect(() => {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
 
  fetch(URL, {
    signal: abortController.signal,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      ...
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // error handling
    });
 
  return () => {
    abortController.abort();
  };
}, []);
```

For more details, check this https://wanago.io/2022/04/11/abort-controller-race-conditions-react/